# c++ how to call static function of another class in namespace

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, in the following code, I want to call the `A::f` function

```cpp
namespace Top
{

class B
    {
  public:
    void hello()
    {
      Top::A::f();
    }
    };

class A
    {
    public:
    static void f()
    {
      printf("123\n");
    }
    };
}

int main()
{
  Top::B b;
  b.hello();

  return 0;
}
```

But the following error appeared

```cpp
Error C2039 "f": not a member of "Top" 
Error C3083 "A": The symbol on the left side of "::" must be a type 
Error C3861 "f": Cannot find identifier
```

How can I fix my code, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call a function before it is declared. Switch the two classes such that when you define `B` the compiler already knows `A::f`:

```
namespace Top
{
class A
    {
    public:
    static void f()
    {
      printf("123\n");
    }
    };

class B
    {
  public:
    void hello()
    {
      Top::A::f();
    }
    };
}

int main()
{
  Top::B b;
  b.hello();

  return 0;
}
```

PS: Not the topic of this question, but don't misuse `static` methods when you actually want a free function inside a namespace. C++ prefers free functions over member functions when possible. Any method that does not need to be a member helps for a cleaner class design.

Comment: As alternatives, I would mention `::Top::A::f()` and `A::f()`. They may be more safe.

Comment: @DanielLangr whats the advantage of `::Top::A::f()` vs `Top::A::f()`? I mean I know the difference, but how is it better?

Comment: Because if, for instance, someone in the future extends the namespace `Top` by a nested namespace `Top` with another function `f`, or by a class/struct `Top` with a static member function `f`, it may call it instead of the original one. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/dr6nEW. I know it's relatively unlikely, but best practices are best practices :). And, it may be more likely in real-world scenarios.